# Dynamically infer the keys of one property based on another

Tags: typescript

Is it possible with typescript to infer the keys of an object `bar` based dynamically on the values of a list of objects `foo`.

Concretely: Given the following

```js
interface Foo {
  name: string;
}

// How should this be defined such that the keys are the union of the `name` values within `foo`
type Bar = Record<???, string>;

interface Example {
  foo: Foo[];
  bar: Bar;
}
```

How should `Bar` be defined such that this is valid:

```js
const example: Example = {
  foo: [
    { name: 'baz' },
  ],
  // Enforced that bar is an object of shape Record<'baz', string>
  bar: {
    baz: 'abc',
  },
};
```

Edit:

In other words - can the type `KeyName` here by dynamically inferred from an instance of an object?

```js
type KeyName = 'aaa' | 'bbb';

interface Foo<T> {
  name: T;
}

interface Example<T> {
  foo: Foo<T>[];
  bar: Record<T, string>;
}

const example: Example<KeyName> = {
  foo: [
    { name: 'aaa' },
    { name: 'bbb' },
  ],
  bar: {
    aaa: '123',
    bbb: '456',
  },
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question.
Are you asking about `keyof` operator?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL664D07yAEugO5UAFugCuAGwAmyMIOCVkAIxQSIMUBCmURCQdMFwwelAGsIAT3lwoKGShEhg6EMnQwjyAAZFSH5ADc4MREIeT5gGVBPGEwPXDAzAAcUACErZABeZAAlCAR0KAkAHlMzVzRMABoqGnoAPiZcUEhYRBQAUQAPEgSxFDwCaPQKDHQAbQBdJgIFKwpUqCZmIA

Comment: @captain-yossarian nope, seems like they are asking how to map a property of values of tuple of objects to keys of an object

Comment: Is this works wor you https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBtAUFKBvKA7AQwFsIAuKAcgCMCAvCqAXwBpMd9izKbgiC8GjdAF0A3OnShIUAEJ1kONqgAKUAJZ5YCVHgCuRKhABOw1BUIkKw4eQoBnOCShgjcMBXSMgA

Comment: Not quite @captain-yossarian . I've just added a second example. I basically want TS to infer what `KeyName` is at runtime based on the values of `Foo.name` within `Example`

Comment: @StickyCube please keep in mind, there are no types in runtime. In runtime you have pure javascript. TS in only in your IDE